# Can we have Dictionary that is concurrent and hybrid in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am new to Python.

Currently I am developing a Python project. For it, there is a need for thread safe hybrid dictionary.

Is there any thread safe *dictionary for python like hybrid dictionary in C#*? I would appreciate some good answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python doesn't offer a hybrid dict natively.  For the most part, it has no need for a blend between list-style storage and hashtable-style storage.

The dict methods are thread-safe in the sense that they don't break the dict invariants when used in a multi-threaded environment (you won't segfault or break the dict).  However, a number of the operations aren't atomic (hashing and equality tests, for example, can make callbacks into pure python code), so you can avoid race conditions by using locks around the relevant operations.